# Depth of seas on a Banks Orbital

Tags: science-based, environment, geography, megastructures, sea

If one is building a Banks Orbital or other megastructure with a very large habitable surface area, it is not necessarily given that much of the area would consist of seas, but there are several reasons why it might. Supposing it does, what would be a likely depth range for the water?

This is one way in which the topology of such structures is expected to differ from a planet. Above sea level, there are practical as well as aesthetic, recreational and ecological reasons for building mountains at least superficially similar to those of Earth. But below, it would seem that deep oceans would be expensive (in terms of the mass of water, and the extra thickness of unobtainium in the loadbearing structure required to support that extra mass), unnecessary and positively undesirable.

Unnecessary in that we only really use the top layer of the sea, for swimming, boats etc.

And undesirable in that shallow water is more biologically productive; when the minerals contained in the sediments at the bottom of the sea are closer to the sunlight, you get more algae, which means you get more fish.

Just what would be the likely depth of the sea on a megastructure? Google says the biggest ships have draft in the range 25-30m. Is there a reason not to make the open oceans a uniform 30m deep?

Comment: Wouldn't the rotation of the structure lead to serious sideways forces on free standing water? Seems like a great way to generate a lot of tidal drag, or perpetual tidal waves scouring the surface. If there are transportation concerns couldn't some form of transport network just be built into the superstructure?

Comment: @sphennings That's a very interesting question! Are you talking about solar tides creating a bulge in the water, that tries to lag behind the rotation of the structure? Is there a way to quantify what the effect might be?

Comment: Think less gravity from remote bodies and more like the forces that push water up the sides of a glass when you spin it fast. Liquids in a spinning tube aren't as nicely coupled to the outside surface as solids are, weird force vectors in a rotational frame don't result in easily navigable bodies of water.

Comment: @sphennings I don't understand what you're getting at here. Water gets pushed up the side of a glass because of the centrifugal force and gravity acting at right angles to each other. In this case, centrifugal force would be the only force acting.

Comment: i would make them at least deep enough for recreational diving, which is more than 30m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The critical question to ask is "*what is the purpose of the ocean?*" or if you'd like to rephrase it, "*what are the negative effects of having an ocean of this particular size?*"

There are a vast number of things that the seas of a megastructure can be used for... off the top of my head,

- Coolant reserve
- Radiation shielding reserve
- Atmospheric gas buffer ([by absorbing/releasing gasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_carbon_cycle))
- Nutrient buffer (biomass in deep oceans is less readily available)
- Atmospheric temperature regulator
- Greater resistance to salinity changes caused by water loss/gain.
- Food source ([mariculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariculture))
- Wildlife preserve
- Recreation
- Aesthetics

Shallow seas restrict the kinds of vegetation and animal life that can live in them, and their limited volume means they can do less to regulate temperature and atmospheric composition. They'd be more vulnerable to dramatic changes like big algal blooms that cause major changes in nutrient or dissolved gas availability, either of which could present a threat to an ecosystem that hadn't been carefully engineered to be robust to such changes.

Depending on the nature of the weather on the habitat, you may find that in the event of strong storm winds, shallow seas will get stirred up more (not necessarily good for your ecosystem) and you might get big waves forming and breaking far from shore, where deep oceans would have undisturbed lower layers and fewer breaking waves (because waves generally break when the water is too shallow to support them).

On the flip-side, shallow seas will be less prone to the formation of large-scale strong currents caused by coriolis effects. Building baffles (eg. marine mountain ranges) in very deep oceans is quite a lot more effort than building barriers in shallow water, but honestly by the time you're building planetary-scale megastructures like this I suspect that throwing in a few extra mountain ranges won't be a significant challenge.

So, after all that,

> Just what would be the likely depth of the sea on a megastructure?

It'll be as deep and expansive as you want it to be. The Culture's orbitals had democratic input into their landscaping, that's as good a model as anything.

The seas will have *enough* depth and volume to fulfil the ecosystem and atmospheric needs of the builders, and they'll have *enough* pretty and interesting shallow water and coastal environments to fulfil the aesthetic and leisure needs and expectations of the occupants.

I can't define "*enough depth and volume for the ecosystem and atmosphere*" because that's an astonishingly complex subject that I don't know that modern science understands well enough to answer. You will be just fine in handwaving any depth you wanted, using the excuse that the super science and/or intelligence of the builders is sufficient to balance out everything else.

Comment: For any rotating megastructure, having a large reserve of mass you can pump aground to keep it balanced is also a big benefit (more so for small structures to be fair).

Comment: @jaketmp I'd be worried about the sort of event that would unbalance something the size of an orbital. Does seem relevant to smaller structures though, and there's the fun possibility of pumping water into rim or hub tanks in order to change the spin rate of the station and change the current gravity...